# Data selector site:current-user:roles: for parameter account is invalid

Tags: drupal

ive got this error on my rules.. i dont know what to do now.

so basically i want to redirect anonymous users to some page when they are adding items to the cart.

but i got this error under data selector

`Data selector site:current-user:roles: for parameter account is invalid.`

[image]

i try searching for this, they said to disable uuid but im not using it.

any tips? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use just `site:current-user`, this reference the user with all parameters.